# PostGIS query: filter rows by area?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, carto

I am working with PostGIS (in CartoDB). I want to find all rows in the database with an area of over 100 square metres. I've been trying this:

```
SELECT *, 
       ST_AREA(the_geom::geography) AS area
FROM mytable
WHERE ST_AREA(the_geom::geography) > 100
```

but I get an error:

```
column cartodb_id must appear in the GROUP BY clause 
or be used in an aggregate function
```

Is it possible to do this directly, or do I need to create an intermediate table?

Comment: It is possible to do that directly. In fact, that query should work exactly as written. `ST_Area` is not an aggregate function so it will act on all rows of your table. Maybe you had a spare `GROUP BY` or aggregate function kicking around?

Comment: Try to remove "*", it seems  CartoDB adds something to your query (e.g. cadtodb_id column).